# Selenium web driver not able to inspect/find the "Select" html tag (combo box)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using SeleniumChrome Driver. I used Xpath, id, and name attributes to inspect "Select" HTML tag. but for some reason it not able to find this tag. Attached is the image .

I tried with xpath:

```
WebElement aSelectWebEleAccountNumber = achromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='accountNumberGroupSelect']"));
```

Tried with CSSSelector:

```
WebElement ass = achromeDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#accountNumberGroupSelect"));
```

Tried with the name attribute. It canf't find the "select" tag.

```
WebElement ass = achromeDriver.findElement(By.name("sections(ACCOUNT_INFO).accountNumberGroup.selectedLookupKey"));
```

**Here is the HTML source,**

[Select Element tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8LTf.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: HTML comboboxes can be implemented in weird ways. You should share the page in question if you want a proper answer.

Comment: I added the "Select" tag in my post

Comment: Nothing wrong with all your locator strategy, it will worked, maybe it inside `iframe`, or other issue. So for solved your issue, please share full html, better if not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement combobox by using Select class directly.

But at first check that the element which you are trying to locate is enabled or not

Answer (score 0):

Try  `achromeDriver.findElement(By.id(...))` ?

In C#, there is a SelectElement class to wrap the select element operations, there might be implementation in your language as well.